# Class deleted before instances : force the deletion order?

Tags: python-3.x, garbage-collection, destructor

I was trying to handle `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` when I encountered a little problem with instance/class cleaning with the garbage collector :

```
class A:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, x):
        A.count += 1
        self.x = x
        print("A instance created :")
        A.class_foo()

    def __del__(self):
        print("destructor :")
        print("A instance (%d) deleted :" % self.x)
        A.count -= 1
        A.class_foo()

    @classmethod
    def class_foo(cls):
        print("Class A count : " + str(cls.count))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a1 = A(1)
    a2 = A(2)
    del a1
    #del a2
```

When running the following code I got the following :

```
$ python test.py
A instance created :
Class A count : 1
A instance created :
Class A count : 2
destructor :
A instance (1) deleted :
Class A count : 1
destructor :
A instance (2) deleted :
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'" in <bound method A.__del__ of <__main__.A instance at 0x1067fe098>> ignored
```

It looks like `A` doesn't exist anymore when the garbage collector deletes my remaining instances.

Is there a way to force the deletion order the Garbage Collector uses? Or is explicitly deleting each instance/class the only way to avoid this kind of problem? (I don't have this error when uncommenting `del a2` in my code for instance).

**EDIT :**

Here is the python I use :

> Python 3.5.1 (default, Apr  4 2016, 12:30:47) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible
>   Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)] on darwin

Since the garbage collector behaviour may depend of the Python implementation, I think it could be important.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce, and I don't see why `A` would be replaced with None regardless of the order of deletion (if you did `del A` I'd expect a `NameError`)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen What's the python implementation you use? Maybe it depends of that, I think the garbage collector behaviour may depend of this. But I have no problem when trying `del A`.

Comment: I use Cpython, running v3.5 on a mac.  if you `del A` **before** instances are deleted it should raise a `NameError: name 'A' is not defined` inside the `__del__`.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen http://dpaste.com/0R4814Z I have no such problem. I added the informations about the Python implementation I use.

Comment: `del A ; del a1` will raise a `NameError` but that is very clearly not the issue here so it doesn't really matter anymore.  Are you sure there is not more going on in the script you run?  Even when I add `None.count` to the `__del__` I get a different error message starting with `Exception ignored in:`